# Ignore all folders with a certain name in SVN (subversion), how to?

Tags: svn, apache, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am fairly new to Subversion and was wondering how exactly to ignore all folders by a specific name.  From what I have read, I think I need to use the `svn:ignore` function, but I have no clue on how to actually do this.  Some places mention a config file.. some say command prompt.

I have my subversion repo set up on a windows 2008 server.  I tried to go to command prompt and type `svn:ignore name` but that didnt work.  The tutorial I used to set up my repo (with apache 2.2) had me create an etc folder in c:/.  There I have subversion.conf, svn-acl and svn-auth-file.

My subversion.conf file includes this:

```
<Location /btp>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath C:/Files/Work/Repositories/btp

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "By The Pixel Repo"
  AuthUserFile c:/etc/svn-auth-file

  Require valid-user

  AuthzSVNAccessFile c:/etc/svn-acl
</Location>
```

The client I use for my development machines is tortoisesvn.

Im a bit of a noob so any help is appreciated it!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TortoiseSVN the way to do it is

1. Right-click on working copy
2. TortoiseSVN --> Properties
3. New
4. svn:ignore

The above is for a particular folder that you have checked out.  If you want to globally ignore something all the time for your Subversion installation go to

1. TortoiseSVN Settings
2. General
3. Global ignore pattern

Comment: If you use Windows and TortoiseSvn, there is submenu to do that. http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html

Answer (score 1):

See [the docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html) on `properties`: `svn:ignore` is a property, so you can set it with `svn propset` as a command, edit it with `svn propedit`, etc.  Halfway down the page at that URL you'll find the precise docs for special property `svn:ignore`.

Comment: could you show me a sample command, i have a hard time understanding the documentation.

Comment: To have SVN ignore file `foo` in the current directory, use command `svn propset svn:ignore foo .` at the shell prompt.

Comment: Such use (AFAIR) will overwrite the previously set `svn:ignore` property value with the new one. Safer choice is `svn propedit svn:ignore .`.

Comment: #gorsky, sure, `propset` **sets** a property's value -- I was just giving the simplest possible example given the OP's request (didn't want him to find himself lost in `vi` or something;-).